# Checkbox values invisible

Tags: html, checkbox

In my html, I am displaying checkboxes. My problem is, the values are set (as seen in Chrome debugger) but it's not visible to the browser. I have tried Firefox and Chrome to no avail. I also unlinked the CSS, but still the problem exists.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check boxes don't work like that, you just have to put the value next to it, using a `<label>` or something.

Comment: Oh my! Please forgive my ignorance. I was getting used to buttons and text for the input tag LOL. Thanks for the help. The description or text for the checkbox is set beside it now. It doesn't look centered to the box but that should do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check boxes don't work like that, you just have to put the value next to it, using a `<label>` or something:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="criterias[]" value="Beauty"> <label for="1">Beauty</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the attribute `value` for a different reason !!

Value is used to assign a value to the element !

You have to mention the text to be displayed like below !

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I love bikes
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I hate cars
```